# windows 7 driver ioctl call

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, kernel

I have written a windows driver for some specific functionality. It works without any issues. However, I am facing issues when invoking it through ioctl interface.

Inside my application, I call CreateFile and try to pass the name which I have given to my driver. However, it gives me an error, "unable to open device" and error code is 0x03. I am using exactly the same name which I have given to my driver.

Name to open the driver from cmd line application: \DosDevice\my_driver
Name passed to CreateFile is also the same. 
Is there any way to find what is the name of my driver in windows namespace?

Answer (score 2):

Win 32 error 0x03 is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND. Try adding "\\.\" to the front of you device name. So it becomes "\\.\DosDevice\my_driver", or it could simply be "\\.\my_driver",   Just to make that clear that is 2 slashes, a dot, then another slash. This should put you into the device namespace, otherwise i believe that CreateFile is just trying to open a file on the file system.

Comment: I did try that initially but did not work mysteriously. Is there any way to read the windows namespace. Can I go and read the name of my driver when it gets installed. I am just wondering if there is some error in the name which is getting registered with windows.

Comment: Is there anything to do with compilation with UNICODE enabled? Do, I need to explicitly enable unicode for my application.

Comment: Got the answer. We need to specify "_UNICODE" in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinObjEx utility to check if your driver creates a device and what name it has: http://www.freewebs.com/four-f/